# Where is this cronjob running?

Tags: cron

We have a news server running on a CentOS 6.5 box.  It's leafnode, and a cron is set to run every two minutes.  We decide to shut it down to troubleshoot other issues, so we comment out the line in the crontab:

```
# */2 * * * * /usr/sbin/fetchnews
```

For some reason, however, we're still getting news articles updated.  So we decide to change the permissions of that binary.

```
chmod 400 /usr/sbin/fetchnews
```

Then, we start to get e-mails every two minutes: '/usr/sbin/fetchnews: permission denied'.

We look in /etc/cron/hourly, in fact in everything to do with crond in /etc.  It's not in root's crontab file, it's not in the news user's crontab file, and it's not in any other user's crontab file.

How can I find out what is causing this binary to be run?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `grep -ri fetchnews /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron/tabs/*`. Are there any more results besides the line you commented out?

Comment: Cron has a log file.  If cron is running the fetchnews, it will be logged.  What's in your /var/log/cron file?

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep -ri fetchnews /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron/tabs/*`.

Are there any more results besides the line you commented out?

Answer (score 0):

```
watch "ps -ef | grep fetchnews"
```

will show you the output of `ps -ef | grep fetchnews` every two seconds. In the output of `ps -ef`, the parent pid is the third field, 1458 in this case:

```
ulmi      1462  1458  0 18:20 pts/1    00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef | grep ls
```

That's the job that spawned your fetchnews, and it might help you on.

(My crystal ball says that maybe you tried to edit the crontabs directly? Only running `crontab -e` is guaranteed to make `crond` pick up the new tab.)

Comment: Your crystal ball's wrong.  :-)  But I very much appreciate your advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a user that owns the news files there's likely a cron entry in this user's personal crontab entry which is responsible for this. User crons are maintained here on RHEL systems:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 4
-rw-------. 1 slm slm 9 Oct  6 13:30 slm
```

If you see entries there you can use `sudo` to see what's in a given file like so:

```
$ sudo crontab -u slm -l
### blah
```

You can simply comment out the entries in this file, using `crontab` to disable it from running. If your work is fairly brief you could also disable the cron service temporarily:

```
$ sudo service crond stop
```